# Server not starting in IBM API connect toolkit

Tags: apiconnect

I have created API's in API connect toolkit. For testing the API locally in Explore tab, I am trying to start server.

But getting "Error: It appears that Docker for Windows has not been installed. To install Docker for Windows, please visit https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/ For more information, check the docs" error.

From my understanding you don't need docker to test locally in toolkit. Any suggestions to fix the issue?

More Info: APIC version: API Connect: v5.0.8.3 (apiconnect: v2.7.209) NPM version : 6.1.0

It used to work before suddenly I am getting the above error. I tried re-installing but issue persist.

Answer (score 1):

With new versions of APIC you must have Docker installed and working properly on your Windows environment to be able to install the API Connect Toolkit with DataPower.

Please find the steps to install the APIC toolkit on these pages:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFS6T/com.ibm.apic.toolkit.doc/tapim_cli_install.html

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFS6T/com.ibm.apic.toolkit.doc/tapim_apic_test_with_dpdockergateway.html